# How to increase contrast for MUI dark theme for modals

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am use MUI dark mode for a Next.js application. MUI modal works well in light mode, but I am having a difficult time finding the edge of the modal when dark theme is toggled. The contrast is really weak. You can't tell where the backdrop is when dark mode has been enabled. Are there any MUI based solutions that can increase modal contrast?

[image: modal with light theme]
[image: modal with dark mode]

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom [BackdropComponent](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/modal/), for example: [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/simplebackdrop-demo-material-ui-forked-x68fcf?file=/demo.js)